Invariant Hahn-Banach theorem
I'm solving the following problem:
Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{Y} \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ be a vector subspace. Let $p: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sublinear functional.
Let $\Gamma$ be an abelian semigroup of linear operators on $\mathcal{X}$ such that:

$A\mathcal{Y} \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$ for all $A \in \Gamma$,
$p(Ax) \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$ and all $A \in \Gamma$.

Show that given a linear functional $f: \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$f(Ay) = f(y)$ for all $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ and all $A \in \Gamma$
$f(y) \leq p(y)$ for all $y \in \mathcal{Y}$,

there exists a linear functional $F: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$F|_{\mathcal{Y}} = f$
$F(Ax) = F(x)$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$ and all $A \in \Gamma$
$F(x) \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$.

I know that in Rudin's book there is a very similar statement called Invariant Hahn-Banach (5.24):



However, I need to prove it in a slightly different way than shown there. The approach I need to use involves constructing a new functional
$$
q:\mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}\\
x\mapsto \inf_{\substack{n\in\mathbb{N}\\ A_{1},\dots,A_{n}\in\Gamma}}\left(\frac{p(A_{1}x) + \dots + p(A_{n}x)}{n}\right)
$$
it is not difficult to check that $q$ is subadditive and has a property of non-negative homogeneity, therefore is also a sublunar functional. The idea is to show the original statement using domination by this functional. But I don't understand how to go further.

Here is a proof using a slightly different definition of $q$. First assume wlog that $I\in \Gamma$. Define $q$ by $$q(x)=\inf_{\substack{n\in\Bbb N\\ A_1,\dots,A_n\in\Gamma}}\frac1np((A_1+\dots+A_n)x).$$
$q$ is subadditive positive homogeneous and satisfies $q\leq p$, $f\leq q\rvert_{\mathcal Y}$. Thus, by the usual Hahn-Banach there exists $F:\mathcal X\to\Bbb R$ such that $F\rvert_{\mathcal Y}=f$ and $F\leq q$. Then $F\leq p$, so we only have to show that $F$ is invariant under $\Gamma$. Let $A\in\Gamma$. By replacing $x$ by $-x$ it suffices to show that $F(Ax)\leq F(x)$ or equivalently $F(Ax-x)\leq 0$. We have\begin{align*}
F(Ax-x) &\leq q(Ax-x)\leq \frac1np((I+A+\dots+A^{n-1})(Ax-x)) = \frac1np(A^nx-x)\\
&\leq \frac1n(p(A^nx)+p(-x))\leq\frac1n(p(x)+p(-x))
\end{align*}
Now let $n\to\infty$.

Hey! Thanks for the feedback! Can you please explain why's it enough to show that $F(Ax)\le F(x)$ (how does the equality rise up from here)? And also since we're dealing only with powers of A why do we need commutativity of $\Gamma$?

You get the equality when applying the inequality to $-x$. The commutativity is used to show that $q$ is subadditive.
